# Couchbase subdocument select only field needed

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I need to select only one field from the subdocument.

ex. original document

```
{
   "geo" : {
      "lat" : 37.700967,
      "alt" : 5622,
      "lon" : -113.098847
   },
   "tz" : "America/Denver",
   "id" : 3824,
   "type" : "airport",
   "city" : "Cedar City",
   "country" : "United States",
   "icao" : "KCDC",
   "faa" : "CDC",
   "airportname" : "Cedar City Rgnl"
}
```

I want it as

```
{ 
    "geo" : { "alt" : 5622 }, 
    "tz" : "America/Denver", 
    "id" : 3824, 
    "type" : "airport", 
    "city" : "Cedar City", 
    "country" : "United States", 
    "icao" : "KCDC", 
    "faa" : "CDC", 
    "airportname" : "Cedar City Rgnl" 
}
```

I need to select only "alt" field from the "geo" sub document however when I refer it as geo.alt in the query it returns as field of main document. I need to preserve the full document structure as it is.

```
SELECT airportname, city, country, geo.alt FROM `travel-sample` WHERE type="airport"
```

Any advise?

Comment: Please post your exact query and your exact results, LIMIT 1. Use copy and paste to be exact.

Comment: Sorry geraldd I don't have access to my development system as of now. I copied orignal document format and format I need as an out put of query. If you observed I want "geo" subdocument in result but it contains only "alt" field. I need it that way.

Comment: When you have your system, copy and paste the exact query and results, LIMIT 1. Then we can take a look.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `I need to select only "alt" field` is in contradiction with `I need to preserve the full document structure`